# calling a variable in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, loops

i have written two seperate scripts in php. one  of them is parsing xml data and the other one is date sorting.

*xml parsing*

```
<?php 


$date = date ("d.m.Y");
$url = "http://www.cbar.az/currencies/" .$date. ".xml";


$doc = new DOMDocument(); 

$doc->load($url); 

$valyutalar = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "Valute" ); 


foreach( $valyutalar as $valyuta ) 
{ 
  $nominal = $valyuta->getElementsByTagName( "Nominal" ); 
  $nom = $nominal->item(0)->nodeValue; 

  $code = trim($valyuta->getAttribute('Code'));


  $value = $valyuta->getElementsByTagName( "Value" ); 
  $val = $value->item(0)->nodeValue;   

 echo "<b>".$code." - " .$val. "AZN\n</b><br>-----------------------<br>";


  }
   ?>
```

date

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
  $beginning = "25.11.1993";
  $ending = date("d.m.Y");
  $date = $beginning;


  while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($ending))
  {
  /* echo "$date<br />"; */
  $date = date ("d.m.Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
  }
?>
```

i want to join thetse two, for parsing  the data from 1993 to now. i`m aware of that i have to put the parser in a while loop but have no any idea exactly where to put. can anyone give an archimedean point just to start? -))

Comment: DateTime object plus DateTimePeriod plus an actualy FileSystem Iterator based on it then rerunting the XML and you're fine within a single foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $date is iterating +1 day in your while loop correctly, then:

```
while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($ending))
  {
  /* echo "$date<br />"; */
  $date = date ("d.m.Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

 $url = "http://www.cbar.az/currencies/" .$date. ".xml";


$doc = new DOMDocument(); 

$doc->load($url); 

$valyutalar = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "Valute" ); 


foreach( $valyutalar as $valyuta ) 
{ 
  $nominal = $valyuta->getElementsByTagName( "Nominal" ); 
  $nom = $nominal->item(0)->nodeValue; 

  $code = trim($valyuta->getAttribute('Code'));


  $value = $valyuta->getElementsByTagName( "Value" ); 
  $val = $value->item(0)->nodeValue;   

 echo "<b>".$code." - " .$val. "AZN\n</b><br>-----------------------<br>";


  }
}$u
   ?>
```

so if $date is incrementing, each time the while loop is triggered, it will load your $url with the next iteration of $date